# Caching console output in Java

Tags: java, caching, console

I am calling a native console executable from Java code using `ProcessBuilder`. This requires me to get an `InputStream` from the child process (which will receive `stdout` and optionally `stderr`) and process its data, to prevent the process from blocking due to buffer exhaustion.

There is a GUI to display the output, but it may not get created/opened until the process has started running (or even finished). However, the user needs to see the entire output (UX similar to GitLab CI).

So my idea is to create a helper class that reads the input stream from the moment the child process is started, and caches the data so it can be displayed later.

The buffer is read in a loop like this:

```
int nRead;
byte[] buff = new byte[size];
while ((nRead = in.read(buff)) != -1)
    // process the data
```

We are talking about console output, thus:

- Data volume can be anything from below 1K to several megabytes of data. The true amount is unknown, thus pre-allocating a buffer would risk either wasting memory or running out at some point. A dynamically growing structure is preferred.
- The data itself consists of human-readable strings.
- Without knowing details of how Java delivers console output, I would expect most data to arrive one line at a time (usually below 80 characters), possibly multiple lines in one burst, sometimes just one character at a time (think primitive progress indicators).
- The cache only needs to support appending data – altering something in the cache is not a use case. However, there is also no need to actively prevent alteration of data.
- I need to be able to retrieve data any number of times (not just once), possibly adding data in between.

Structures that came to mind are either some form of `List<String>`, with the data from each iteration converted into a string that is then appended to the list. Drawback is that storage overhead can get very large if data arrives in tiny chunks – for data arriving one character at a time, storage overhead would likely be a multiple of the payload. Also, what `List` subclass is the preferred one for an append-only use case – `ArrayList`, `LinkedList` or something else?

Another candidate would be `StringBuilder`, in conjunction with the `append()` method.

Question: What is the most efficient approach?

- How does the `InputStream` for a console application in Java receive data? Does one cycle of the receiving loop roughly correspond to a `print` operation by the child process, or does data get split and merged – and if so, does that happen in a somewhat predictable manner?
- What are considerations for choosing `size`, i.e. the size of `buf`?
- Which of the data structures is more efficient in terms of memory usage (performance is probably less of an issue)? Or is there a better alternative that I haven’t thought of?

Comment: I would try to `transerTo` a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and then create a string from it or write it to a file

Comment: I would guess how the `InputStream` receives data is implementation dependent. You shouldn't worry about that too much. Instead, just use the `InputStream` based on how it's defined to work. Note the `InputStream` is giving you _bytes_, not characters. If you know you're getting text output, then you need to decode those bytes into characters. The easiest way to do that is to wrap the `InputStream` in a `Reader`. Note you'll need to choose an appropriate character encoding. Then just continually read characters from the `Reader` until there's no more to read.

Comment: From there, I would try simply appending the characters to a `StringBuffer` / `StringBuilder`. See if that works well enough for you before you try to implement more complicated solutions. The `StringBuffer` / `StringBuilder` would function as your cache. When ready, have your UI register a listener (you'll have to write the code for listeners, or e.g., maybe use an existing reactive library) that is immediately notified of the cached data, then subsequently notified of any new data as it comes in.

Comment: @Slaw why not make this an answer (so I can upvote and accept it)? Btw, as I found out, `StringBuilder#toString()` can be called any number of times on the same instance, making it a suitable solution for attaching a GUI more than once and getting output from the start each time. Last remaining question: how do I know what character encoding the console uses? OS is Android, by the way.

Comment: A `StringBuilder` will use more memory than a `ByteArrayOutputStream` since you're appending not `byte`s but `char`s, which are twice as long. They will be on a par *at the end* (when the final `String` is created) but not leading to the end

Comment: @g00se Depends on the implementation. `String` / `StringBuilder` / `StringBuffer` in modern versions of OpenJDK-based Java use a `byte[]` for storage, which will only use two bytes per char if needed. Not sure what Android does though.

Comment: @user149408 If you notice a memory problem with `StringBuilder` then you can use `ByteArrayOutputStream` as suggested by g00se. To change it to a `String` you can simply do `new String(baos.toByteArray(), encoding)`. The reason I suggested a `StringBuilder` and `Reader` is I _think_ it'd make it easier to work with characters. At least if you want to keep everything in memory. As for knowing which character encoding to use, not sure. Perhaps all Android devices use the same encoding and that's documented somewhere. Or maybe you can query the information somehow.